# Postfix: inbound and outbound relay with store and forward - advice needed

Tags: email, smtp, postfix, dovecot, relay

My ISP blocks port 25, so I'd like to setup a store and forward inbound and outbound postfix server (relay-server) that communicates with a mailstore server (mailstore-server), which is unable to receive or send directly to the internet.

- The mailstore-server will host multiple email domains (user1@domain1.tld, user2@domain2.tld, etc).
- The mailstore-server will then send and receive via the relay-server.
- The relay-server will be set as the mx server for all the email domains, and then just forward the email from the internet to the mailstore-server and from the mailstore-server to the internet.
- Users will connect directly to the mailstore-server for IMAP or for webmail as that will run Dovecot, and they will use the mailstore-server for sending mail too.
- Mail volumes are expected to be low. It is for family mail only.

I have read numerous articles and done a tonne of research on various options, but most options and articles talk to using the relay-server purely as an outbound sending server and with the mailstore-server being able to receive from the internet directly. I am struggling to find advice on how to get both working, with the mailstore-server using only the relay-server as the send and receive, and with store and forward functionality on the relay-server.

Advice would be appreciated on the following:

1. I assume the concept, from what I understand is: use Postfix on the relay-server and then Postfix and Dovecot server on the mailstore-server. The relay-server will have port 25 open for receiving and sending and also port 587, and the mailstore-server will talk to the relay-server on port 587 only.
2. I understand I will have to use authentication between the two servers to allow them send, but am confused on what to do as there is mention of LDAP, SASL and then individual user authentication per user/domain?
3. I would prefer for users to connect to the mailstore-server and send emails from there. I understand they could connect to the relay-server to send emails, but having them connect to the relay-server means they have to have specific logins there too. Which I would prefer avoiding the duplication.
4. I would like to have the simplest setup possible. Ideally, all users and mailboxes, with sending and receiving for users done on the mailstore-server, and then the relay-server is purely a smtp gateway back and forth for the mailstore-server, with the functionality to store mail if my home connection is offline for a bit. I understand I will have to update the sending domains for the relay-server if I add/remove hosted domains.
5. Virus Scanning and SPAM. Where should this be done? The intention is to use the smallest/cheapest server as the relay-server, something like a $5 vps server. Can I do the virus/spam protection on the server at home? Or must it be done/should it be done at the relay-server as mail is passing through? I see there are options like postgrey/sieve, etc too. Where are the best places to implement those?
6. Can I still use certs for the smtp server at the edge, as I assume this is required for TLS, etc?
7. I'd really like to try docker the entire solution and have come across the docker-mailserver (https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver) concept. It looks good, but talks mainly to a full-fledged server and I am struggling to understand where to configure the specific options for the relay-server and the mailstore-server and how to configure them, as they aren't very specific about those and assume that users have an indepth understanding of all the terms and configuration options already, which I unfortunately don't.

Any advice or confirmation of the above points would be very much welcome, with any detail to help in the process. I'm happy to write up a blog or post on this, or post back a guide here as this has taken me long enough to achieve and I'm happy to share the assistance back.

Comment: Why do it this way? Why not just use a VPN (with static IP) to bypass the ISP block, or set the "relay server" up to simply port-forward port 25 to an arbitrary port on your real mail server?

Comment: That's a really good point actually and something I hadn't fully thought about. It adds a lot of value that way. I can keep all the settings I have on the mailstore-server and then just VPN to the VPS (aka relay-server) with a default route and source NAT it there. It doesn't solve the store and forward issue, but mail will retry regardless. I'll see I how I come along doing that instead.